# Saving an image to app properties

Tags: javascript, ios, image, properties, titanium

Hi I'm trying to save an image to the apps properties as part of a JSON array but when i try to display it, the imageview appears blank. The image is grabbed from the phone's gallery when the Upload_pic button is clicked. Code below:

```
Upload_pic.addEventListener('click', function (e){  
        Upload_pic.setImage('/images/uploadPhoto2.png');
        Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success: function(e){
                console.log("typeof e.media --------  " + e.media);
                ImageView=Ti.UI.createImageView({
                    image:e.media
                }).toImage();

            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Error accessing photos");

                Upload_pic.setImage('/images/uploadPhoto1.png');
            },
            cancel: function(e){

                Upload_pic.setImage('/images/uploadPhoto1.png');
            },
            alowEditing:true,
            mediaType:[Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
        });
});
```

and then I'm saving the image on this submit_btn click:

```
 Submit_btn.addEventListener('click', function (e){
            var filename = ID+"-ea.jpg";
            bgImage = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filename);
            bgImage.write(ImageView);

            if (bgImage.exists()) //File ever does not exist.
                 {
                        alert('file '+filename+' exists!!!');
                    // I am getting this alert
                }
                else
                {
                        alert('file '+filename+' IS NOT exist(');
                }

            MyRecipe_info= {name: title_textField.value, ID:ID, Ingredients: ingredients_textField.value, numSteps:numSteps_textField.value, pic:bgImage, steps:numStepsArray};
            Ti.App.Properties.setBool('MyRecipeAdded', true);


            MyRecipes_data.push(MyRecipe_info);
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('MyRecipesData', JSON.stringify(MyRecipes_data));
            alert("Recipe added successfully!");
        });
```

And then i am displaying it here:

```
MyRecipes_data=JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('MyRecipesData'));
for(i=0;i<MyRecipes_data.length;i++){
    var Pic = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        left: '5dp',
        top:'20dp',
        right:'15dp',
        height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
        bottom: '5dp',
        image:MyRecipes_data[i].pic
    });

}
```

Currently working on iOS, but code will need to work on Android in future. Using Titanium SDK 3.3.0.201407100905 and Titanium Classic

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I needed to store the bgImage.nativePath

Answer (score 0):

to store a image in property is bad habit as it takes much memory specially for android so i would suggest to store only image path in that array

or even if possible you should use database to store data instead of using Ti.Property.

Hope you get it.